# How to plot non-uniform bar chart using GNUplot?

Tags: data-visualization, gnuplot

I want to plot using GNUplot a bunch of data that is in this form:

```
123 130 5
```

... where the first number is the x starting value, the second is the x ending value, and the 3rd number is the y value.

Ideally I would plot these in an accumulative/stacked manner.

Is there any easy way to do this with GNUplot?

Comment: UPDATE I found a way to do this by just doing a little C coding to munch on the data. C is so much easier than RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

help boxes
...
      3 columns:  x  y  x_width

so if you did `using 1:3:2 with boxes` you'd be about set.